# Deleting Git Branches

Tags: git, git-branch

Let's say I am on my `master` branch on Git , and I make a new branch called `bad_branch`. After working on this, I realize I want to delete the progress I have made in this branch and only retain the work done in `master` before I made this branch.

If I have not merged `bad_branch` with `master`, then once I do `git branch -d bad_branch`, am I only left with what I want, which is the work I have done in `master` up until I made `bad_branch`?

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: why would you delete it anyway? What if you later decide that work was useful after all... In order to delete it you will probably have to run `git gc` as well.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is confusing.

But a) Yes, the whole point of a "branch" is to do some work *without* affecting the other branches.

b) The correct command to revert back to the master is `git checkout master`.

c) Willem Van Onsem is absolutely correct:

> Why would you delete it anyway? What if you later decide that work was
>   useful after all... In order to delete it you will probably have to
>   run [git gc](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-gc) as well. –